# Adding module name in Gradle build

Tags: gradle, ivy, artifactory, artifact

We just moved from Ant+Ivy builds to Gradle.My project structure is

```
Project A  which has two sub modules : module1 and module2
```

Both module1 and module2 have their own build.gradle files.The problem is when I publish an artifact from module1,I want the artifact pattern to be like :

```
projectA-module1.jar instead of just module1.jar
```

It was pretty simple to do in Ivy using:

```
<info organisation="abc" module="projectA-module1">
```

Is there any way I can change the module name in gradle?

PS: I researched and found out we have group instead of organisation in gradle but not for module name.I am publishing to Artifactory

Thanks.

Comment: How do you publish to Artifactory (which plugin)? Do you use Artifactory as a Maven or Ivy repo?

Comment: As an ivy repo @PeterNiederwieser

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understand, you just want to change the name of the project. It's easy to do in the 'settings.gradle' file. Just set the name of the project to `projectA-module1`:

```
rootProject.name = 'projectA-module1'
```